# Android Studio adding theme material light getting error missing style

Tags: android, android-theme

Android Studio getting error while adding theme material light theme the  error is

> Missing style one or more layout is missing the layout_width or
>   layout_height.
>   [Here is the error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdaML.png)

the snapshot of the error I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message suggests, the layout that you're viewing is using styles that are not present in the theme that the android studio previewer using to show your layout.

There's a combo box above the preview that allows you to choose which theme the previewer will use. You can select the desired theme (material light) to preview with that theme.